# How to know the code flow of a driver module?

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules, debugging, control-flow

I am studying Linux device drivers, my main focus is on wifi drivers.
I want to know how the code flows when I plugin my device. 
Maybe, I can do something like add a `printk` line in every function.
The device I have is supported by `ath9k_htc` driver.
I want to make some changes in the driver code for learning purposes.

What is the correct or general approach for understanding the code flow of driver modules in linux?

Comment: WiFi (networking in general) is a *very* complex area...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When I want to do this, I use [the `ftrace` framework](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/trace/ftrace.html). Start by mounting the special file system:

```
mount -t tracefs nodev /sys/kernel/tracing
```

(as root; you should become root for all this, you’ll be doing everything as root anyway, and it’s easier to have a root shell than to use `sudo`).

Then change to that directory:

```
cd /sys/kernel/tracing
```

It contains a basic `README` which provides a short summary. To explore function calls, I use [the function graph tracer](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/trace/ftrace.html#function-graph-tracer), `function_graph` in `available_tracers`. Identify the functions you’re interested in, for example [`ath9k_htc_tx`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.6/source/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/htc_drv_main.c#L862), and set them up

```
echo ath9k_htc_tx > set_graph_function
```

You can append other functions, make sure to use `>>` after the first function. You can see the configured functions with

```
cat set_graph_function
```

When you write to `set_graph_function`, the function is checked against the running kernel; if the function can’t be found, the write will fail, so you’ll know straight away if you’ll end up not tracing anything.

Once the functions are set up, enable the tracer:

```
echo function_graph > current_tracer
```

then watch the `trace` file. To disable the tracer again,

```
echo nop > current_tracer
```

or flip `tracing_on` by writing 0 or 1 to it (0 to disable tracing, 1 to re-enable it).

Answer (score 1):

The main takeaway is that drivers connect an upper and a lower interface together. In the case of `ath9k_htc`, the lower interface is USB, the upper interface is the network stack.

Control flow is largely a state machine that can react to events arriving from both interfaces without any synchronization, for example it is entirely possible for the network interface to notify the driver to join a multicast group, and at the same time a notification comes in from the USB subsystem that the device was ejected -- in multiprocessor systems, these events can be reported on different CPUs, and the driver will be entered concurrently then.

Most drivers do not have a process or thread context and are purely event-driven, with the event loop external to the driver, so usually you see many small functions handling specific events, attempting to forward them, making a note somewhere if that fails, and immediately returning.

The most sensible way to visualize control flow in a typical driver is to draw a map of shared lockable resources and which functions access them, as a typical line of communication is to lock a list, append data to it, and unlock. If you draw USB related functions on one side, and network related functions on the other of the resources, that should give you the clearest picture.